# How do I properly send a SIGTERM to a dotnet core ASP app running on Mac?

Tags: c#, macos

I have this in my Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("ApplicationStopping called"));
    appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("ApplicationStopped called"));
}
```

I start my dotnet app: `dotnet run --project myapp/myapp.csproj`.

I get the process ID: `ps | grep "dotnet run --project myapp/myapp.csproj"`

I send the process a sigterm: `kill <PID>`.

The app terminates immediately and I don't see my console log messages. kill is supposed to send a SIGTERM by default.

Am I using IApplicationLifetime wrong or am I sending the SIGTERM wrong?

### Edit

I think I might be using IApplicationLifetime wrong because I added this as well and I never see these messages either:

`appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("ApplicationStarted called"));`

Comment: in Mac, are you running dotnet inside shell script, for instance, shell script calls `dotnet app.dll`. For us, adding `exec dotnet app.dll` helped to propagate SIGTERM signal to dotnet application, and not let shell script handle the SIGTERM directly.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime.applicationstopping?view=aspnetcore-6.0) "Triggered when the application host is performing a **graceful shutdown**." which does not looks like kill-ing for windows-born framework.

There are some old threads about how to trigger it manually: [Getting ASP.Net Core shutdown triggering ApplicationStopping event in IISExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267606/getting-asp-net-core-shutdown-triggering-applicationstopping-event-in-iisexpress)
also [asp.net core: IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping isn't triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231148/asp-net-core-iapplicationlifetime-applicationstopping-isnt-triggered)

But if you are *really* want to catch SIGTERM, you need to google "unix signal handlers".

There is a [C API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal?view=msvc-170) for this, there is also [mono implementation](http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/mono/2008/Feb-08.html), and finally there is (or will be soon) [ms implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.posixsignal?view=net-6.0).

Comment: .net is supposed to do this ootb. k8s will send the process a sigterm when the pod is terminated. I need to mimic that locally for testing any logging/shutdown routines.